# I cant import javax.servlet.FilterRegistration with javax.servlet version 2.5

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I'm working with a Spring MVC web application and I'm having troubles with these imports:

```
import javax.servlet.FilterRegistration;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;
```

The error says `The import javax.servlet.FilterRegistration cannot be resolved`

this is my init app (I'm using a java confgi)

```
 public class InitApp implements WebApplicationInitializer {

        @Override
        public void onStartup(ServletContext container) 
        {
            // Create the 'root' Spring application context
            AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
            rootContext.register(RootConfig.class);

            // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
            container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

            // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
            AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherServlet = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
            dispatcherServlet.register(MvcConfig.class);

            // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
            ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherServlet));
            dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
            dispatcher.addMapping("/");

        }

        private void registerCharacterEncodingFilter(ServletContext servletContext) {
            CharacterEncodingFilter encodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
            encodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
            encodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
            FilterRegistration.Dynamic characterEncodingFilter = servletContext.addFilter("characterEncodingFilter", encodingFilter);
            characterEncodingFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
        }
    }

this is my maven dependency
<!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

if i put this maven dependency the error doesn't show anymore

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

but my server gives me this error `“Dynamic Web Module 3.1 requires Java 1.7 or newer”`

are those imports only available if I use javax.servlet-api version 3.1.0

Comment: What Java version are you using? Seems to be 6 or under.

Comment: i'm using Java.SE 1.8

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use classes from the [Java Servlet 3.1](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr340/), you need a server that implements that level of specification (e.g.: Tomcat 8, Wildfly, Glassfish 4).

Otherwise, if you application contains a JAR with some Servlet API, the application server will not load it. You'll get: `jar not loaded`.

By the way, seems to me that possibly with  Servlet 3.0 is more than enough (Tomcat 7, JBoss AS 7, Glassfish 3.x).

Another solution is to use an [older version](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-4.0.html#_java_ee_6_and_7) of Spring.